# do the ids of photos remain static assuming no changes to photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If my app uses the graph api to retrieve the id of a particular photo, will that id always exist as long as the photo it refers to is not modified/deleted out of the users albums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, node/object IDs like the photo id in your case are unique and will exist as long as the photo isn't deleted.